# Golang echo package middleware implementation

Tags: go, middleware, go-echo

I'm learning Go and was going through this example : [echo middleware example](https://echo.labstack.com/cookbook/middleware). I wanted to do a deep dive to understand what was going on when we call `next(c)` in the function middleware function `Process()`.

Looking at the `main()` I understand we append the `Process()` function to the echo `Context` object's list of middleware functions via the `Use()` call. However, looking at the [echo source code](https://github.com/labstack/echo/blob/master/echo.go) I'm unsure how the `next(c)` call in the `Process()` function in the middleware example looks through all of the context's middleware functions. Couple things that I cannot seem to find even after searching the source code:

(1) Where is the function definition for `echo.HandlerFunc` being defined? I see [WrapHandler](https://github.com/labstack/echo/blob/master/echo.go#L761) but that's exported and not used in `echo.go` so I'm confused what happens when `next(c)` gets called what line of code in `echo.go` source code we jump to.

(2) It looks like the loop happens when calling `applyMiddleware` as that seems to loop through all the middleware functions saved in the Context's list of middleware functions but I don't see how that method is called unless you call the exported `WrapMiddleware` function or `ServeHTTP` etc.

Comment: If you're referring to specific source code, please quote the relevant code in the body of your question rather than linking to it externally.

Comment: [`HandlerFunc`](https://godoc.org/github.com/labstack/echo#HandlerFunc) is not a function but a *type*, that's why there is no function definition for it, there is, however, a type definition in the [source code](https://github.com/labstack/echo/blob/master/echo.go#L111) if you're interested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`next(c)` doesn't loop through anything. `next` is a variable received as a function parameter, which contains a function. `next(c)` calls that function. In practice, it is the next part of the chain - which might be the next middleware, or might be the final request handler. When the `func` that `Process` returns is called, that itself might have been called as `next` by the middleware before it.

There's no magic involved, and nothing hidden within the library It's just a chain of function calls.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm still unsure of what happens when a request arrives at `/stats`. Request comes in, how is the middleware `HandlerFunc` `Process` first called? And then let's assume there's a second middleware function to be executed after `Process`. I was wondering how that chain of function calls works. But maybe once I setup my VSCode Go debugger correctly I can just step through it.

Comment: The router (gin in your case) calls the handler registered for a route. You've wrapped the handler in middleware, so the middleware is what the router is actually calling. Then the middleware calls its parameter, and so on.